# Can't see the data in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

My app retrieve the data from sqlite, but I can't see any data on the pages that there is available to highlight the data.

Here is the adapter.

```
private ShoppingDatabaseHandler sdb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping);

    sdb = new ShoppingDatabaseHandler(this) ;

    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" ABC MARKET ", " 27872514 ", " 6 ")); 
    sdb.addShopping(new Shops(" Fortress ", " 27454547 ", " 7 ")); 


    List<Shops> values = sdb.getAllShops();

    ArrayAdapter<Shops> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Shops>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Here is the layout.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I don't know what is the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Here is the ShoppingDatabaseHandler.

```
// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHOP + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL  );";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SHOP);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addShopping(Shops shops) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, shops.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_NUMBER, shops.getNumber()); // Contact Phone
    values.put(KEY_LOCATION, shops.getLocation());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_SHOP, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}


public List<Shops> getAllShops() {
    List<Shops> shopdata = new ArrayList<Shops>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SHOP;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      Shops shops = cursorToShops(cursor);
      shopdata.add(shops);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return shopdata;
  }

private Shops cursorToShops(Cursor cursor) {
    Shops shops = new Shops();
    shops.setName(cursor.getString(0));
    shops.setNumber(cursor.getString(1));
    shops.setLocation(cursor.getString(2));
    return shops;
  }
```

Should I need to add toString() in Cursor function?

Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: Obviously, your values List is empty otherwise your code is fine. Please debug and check whether your list contains any data or not

Comment: Does your list display empty rows? or does it display no rows at all?

Comment: There are empty rows.

Comment: Is there something missing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: post the ShoppingDatabaseHandler, did you debug and check if you get "values" as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't know how to display  "Shops" item, since it's a custom class.
A list view uses object.toString() to display the object, so you need to add a toString() method to Shops that will tell Android how to display it.

for example (adjust to taste), add this in your Shops.java

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return getName() + " (" + getNumber() + " ) located at: " + getLocation();

}
```

Comment: Yes. I got it. I know what I did wrong. Because I just to the toString() in Shop like that.  public String toString() {
         return shops;
     }   So, it is a mistakes. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29) says:

> However the TextView is referenced, it will be filled with the
>   toString() of each object in the array. You can add lists or arrays of
>   custom objects. Override the toString() method of your objects to
>   determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

That means that, if you're having empty rows, your *Shops* object doesn't have a toString() method, or this method returns an empty string.